# How to find the nth largest number's index in a 2-dimensions matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, max

I have a matrix like this
[image]

I want to find the nth largest number's index in this matrix without breaking it, is there any way to do that?

Comment: Create n-element array and fill it with n first numbers sorted descending. Then you go over all the remaining elements and insert them into the array keeping it sorted. If the item doesn't fit in an array (aka it is smaller than n currently highest numbers) you ignore it. At the end last item in the array will be nth largest.

Comment: is this a numpy array?

Comment: yes it is.@ManavChhibber

Answer (score 0):

You could try something as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def get_largest_index(arr, nth):
    
    # flatten array and get index of sort
    flat_ind_sort = arr.flatten().argsort()
    
    # if nth is out of bounds, return smallest
    if nth > len(flat_ind_sort):
        nth = len(flat_ind_sort)
        print('Warning. Supplied nth is out of bounds. Returning smallest')
    
    # last elem will be index of max val
    idx_nth = flat_ind_sort[-1*nth]
    
    # convert flat index into tuple of coords for orig arr (arr.shape)
    coords = np.unravel_index([idx_nth],arr.shape)

    x, y = coords[0][0], coords[1][0]

    return x, y

arr = np.random.rand(2,3)

# array([[0.20719063, 0.03955628, 0.65236656],
#        [0.82384201, 0.11928533, 0.76487719]])

ordinal = lambda n: "%d%s" % (n,"tsnrhtdd"[(n//10%10!=1)*(n%10<4)*n%10::4])

for i in range(1,math.prod(arr.shape)+1):
    coords = get_largest_index(arr, i)
    print(f'{ordinal(i)} largest at {coords}: {arr[coords]}')

# 1st largest at (1, 0): 0.8238420131656327
# 2nd largest at (1, 2): 0.7648771886978403
# 3rd largest at (0, 2): 0.6523665637022131
# 4th largest at (0, 0): 0.20719063448844777
# 5th largest at (1, 1): 0.11928533253344997
# 6th largest at (0, 1): 0.03955627857150146

# error handling nth is out of bounds

coords = get_largest_index(arr, math.prod(arr.shape)+2)
print(f'{ordinal(i)} largest {coords}: {arr[coords]}')

# Warning. Supplied nth is out of bounds. Returning smallest
# 6th largest (0, 1): 0.03955627857150146
```